# Is there any way by which I can save the state of `static members`?

Tags: java, serialization, static, static-members

Just like the way we save the `instance variables` using serialization, is there any way by which I can save the state of `static` members?

If there is a situation, where getting back the state of static members is necessary to restore something, how would one do that?

Comment: using anything, i mean as per my knowledge, we cannot save static members using Serialization, Serialization is for instance members/objects.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Isn't kind of pointless since it's not tied to an object?

Comment: static members of a class would re-construct themselves once a class is loaded into the jvm, so there wouldn't be a need to save that state. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: what do you mean by 'reconstruct'? they will be created, but will be initialized with default value, right? so they are restoring any value i guess.

Comment: @CoolBeans @Salman I'm not a much of a Java user, but static stuff still has state, doesn't it? It might have a bad smell, but I can imagine that there are situations where you would want to recover  static state for a class, rather than just re-initializing it.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: yes, that's exactly what my doubt is.

Comment: @10101010 Using a "Singleton" to store this "static" stuff may be useful here -- it will require modification of the code, and perhaps some reviews if more tricky things are done with the static members. With appropriate control the Singleton object may itself be a static member -- with all the caveats of this. Then the Singleton object can be serialized/deserialized like any other.

Comment: +1 for the singleton, I also suggested it in the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest option that comes to my mind is to use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) rather than static fields. The singleton object can be serialized and deserialized, and you can manage its lifetime, while you preserve the 'global state' that static fields give you (that said, global state is a bad thing, but that's a different topic)

Otherwise - the static state is preserved throughout the lifetime of the classloader (which usually means the lifetime of the JVM). So if you want to persist state, it makes sense to do it on shutdown, and restore it on class load.

- `Runtime.addShutdownHook(..)` to perform the serialization on shutdown
- use a `static {..}` block to load it on next open

The serialization format can be anything. JSON, BSON, java serialization (using `ObjectOutputStream`)

But this is an unusual and in most cases the wrong thing to do. So make sure this is what you want. If you simply want the state to live for the lifetime of the application, don't do anything. And if you want to persist something for longer, either pick the singleton option or consider using a small database rather than static fields.

Comment: While I might use addShutdownHook as a fallback, I'd normally save state at a lot higher level - before there's much opportunity for things to go wrong during shutdown.  A bug there that messed up the save, under certain unknown conditions, would be hell to debug.  +1 on the singleton advices.

Comment: @Ed Staub of course. I will emphasize that this solution is a direct answer to the question, but is in most cases the wrong thing to do