# Is there a way by which i can store a value of a static variable during Serializaion?

Tags: java, serialization, static

In Java , how do we store value of a static variable during Serializaion?

Comment: Where do you *want* to store it?

Comment: Can you expand upon this question? What do you mean by storing it and how do you wish to use it.

Comment: You could write it down on a post it.

Comment: Store where? NameOfMyClass.nameOfField = "value" ?

Comment: Are you talking about serialization? How to serialize static variable?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259454/is-there-a-way-by-which-i-can-store-a-value-of-a-static-variable-during-serializa

Comment: Edited the question. I meant during serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good answer for exactly this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643977/is-there-any-way-by-which-i-can-save-the-state-of-static-members):

"The easiest option that comes to my mind is to use a singleton rather than static fields. The singleton object can be serialized and deserialized, and you can manage its lifetime, while you preserve the 'global state' that static fields give you."

Answer (score 2):

The same as any other field.

```
static String name;

// assign
name = "Bob";

// get
String n = name;
```

If you want to save it to a file, you can use a shutdown hook to write the data, however this is not guaranteed to run.  I would write the data to a file every time it changes and load it on start up.

```
private static final String NAME_FILE = "name.txt";
static String name; static {
  try {
    name = FileUtils.readFileToString(NAME_FILE );
  } catch (IOException e) {
    name = "unknown";
}

public static String getName() { return name; }
public static void setName(String name) { 
   this.name = name;
   try {
      FileUtils.writeStringToFile(NAME_FILE, name);
   } catch(IOException e) {
      log.error(e);
   }
}
```

You can store a variable during serialization by overriding wrireObject/readObject however, this is a bad idea.  You are better off serializing the static value instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize static variables, but you can use only one instance of class instead static. Look to [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, the question is more about storing the value of a static field between applications startups and shutdowns.

(If this assumption is correct then) you have to store the value manually to some external storage (like a text file) and then you can perform a static initialization:

```
static String field;

static {
   field = readFromFile();
}
```

**UPD**: you'll have to override `readObject` method and you'll also have to introduce kind of a static flag variable. In `readObject` method you'll check the flag and if it's not set to `true' (i.e. if static variables aren't initialized yet), you'll do something like in a code snippet above.

I also suppose that it can be necessary to make some synchronization if you have multiple threads.